# Attempting to publish and subscribe to individual portions of an advertised topic

Tags: ros, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys. I've just started using ROS a couple of days back. I'm trying to write a publisher(talker) that will take certain parts of a topic and publish them, and a subscriber that can take whatever this talker is publishing. I know this question sounds a bit vague, but can you help me? I've read the tutorials but I still can't use that to my purpose.

Let's say we have some topic '/XXXX/DATA'. I want to extract, say, '/XXX/DATA.acc_x' using the publisher and send it to the subscriber. Is this even possible?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11813/attempting-to-publish-and-subscribe-to-individual-portions-of-an-advertised-topic/) by [AlgorithmSeeker](https://answers.ros.org/users/1323/algorithmseeker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2011-11-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes it is possible, The data that is available on the topic is specified by messages. In you case I assume you define some message that contains some element like

`float64 acc_x`

for instance. Then you subscribe to this topic and just access the data element via the callback say

`void dataCallback(const SomePkg::SomeMsgTypeConstPtr msg) { float accx = msg->acc_x; }`

And you are set. You can go ahead and do anything with it afterwards.

---

Originally posted by [makokal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31/makokal/) with karma: 1295 on 2011-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-11-16**:
You can also publish in the callback too.